# FFmpeg "piping" doesn't work with mp4 files?

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I try the answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60558412/how-to-decode-a-video-memory-file-byte-string-and-step-through-it-frame-by-f) post and works very well for .webm format. I also try this implementation for mp4 file frames extraction and I got no bytes in stdout. Is there any solution to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

No, its not possible due to the structure of mp4 files. Mp4 files have a frame index at the beginning (sometime the end) of the file that records every frame position and size. Its not possible to generate this index until ever frame has been seen.

It may be possible by using a fragmented m4 by adding the flags `-f mp4 -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov` to the ffmpeg command, But not everything knows how to read that format.