# ffmpeg: error reading header pipe:0: Invalid argument

Tags: go, ffmpeg

I need microservice (converter audio using streams), but have problem with ffmpeg

***my test ffmpeg***

```golang
package codec

import (
    "bytes"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "testing"
)

func Test1(t *testing.T) {
    in, err := os.Open("/mp4-mp3/src.m4a")
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err.Error())
    }
    out, err := os.OpenFile("/mp4-mp3/out.mp3", os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err.Error())
    }
    cmd := exec.Command(
        "ffmpeg",
        "-f", "m4a",
        "-i", "pipe:0",
        "-f", "mp3",
        "pipe:1")

    cmd.Stdin = in
    cmd.Stdout = out
    stderr := &bytes.Buffer{}
    cmd.Stderr = stderr
    if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
        t.Logf(stderr.String())
        t.Fatal(err.Error())
    }

}
```

At the exit, I have the error invalid argument
i tried different options but the problem didn't change

```
=== RUN   Test1
    codec_test.go:31: ffmpeg version git-2020-08-31-4a11a6f Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
          built with gcc 10.2.1 (GCC) 20200805
          configuration: hide...
          libavutil      56. 58.100 / 56. 58.100
          libavcodec     58.101.101 / 58.101.101
          libavformat    58. 51.101 / 58. 51.101
          libavdevice    58. 11.101 / 58. 11.101
          libavfilter     7. 87.100 /  7. 87.100
          libswscale      5.  8.100 /  5.  8.100
          libswresample   3.  8.100 /  3.  8.100
          libpostproc    55.  8.100 / 55.  8.100
        [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000019ccc3acb40] error reading header
        pipe:0: Invalid argument
    codec_test.go:32: exit status 1
--- FAIL: Test1 (0.07s)
FAIL

Process finished with exit code 1
```

i decided to use cmd, but i have new problem
pipe:0: Invalid data found when processing input

```
cat src.m4a | ffmpeg -f m4a -i pipe:0 out.mp3
ffmpeg version git-2020-08-31-4a11a6f Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.2.1 (GCC) 20200805
  configuration: hide...
  libavutil      56. 58.100 / 56. 58.100
  libavcodec     58.101.101 / 58.101.101
  libavformat    58. 51.101 / 58. 51.101
  libavdevice    58. 11.101 / 58. 11.101
  libavfilter     7. 87.100 /  7. 87.100
  libswscale      5.  8.100 /  5.  8.100
  libswresample   3.  8.100 /  3.  8.100
  libpostproc    55.  8.100 / 55.  8.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000019afa98d800] invalid STSD entries 1
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000019afa98d800] error reading header
pipe:0: Invalid data found when processing input
```

How to properly set ffmpeg parameters to convert from stream to stream?

Answer (score 3):

Typically, `mp4` cannot be loaded through `pipe` protocol. The video container cannot be read sequentially. This can be mitigated if the `mp4` is [created with some special flags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62825179/192373), but these may cause some other problems.

Comment: I see the only way to screw the virtual file system. I don't want to touch the HDD(

Comment: It's only with mp4? Or webm and ogg won't work either?

Comment: Some mp4 files will work, too. If you can open the file in python, it will probably be openable also from C. If not, you can either copy the file to an openable location.