# What is the most efficient way to convert wav audio string to an ogg file without writing it to disk?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, wav, ogg, pydub

My final objective is to use TTS to get some Indic text converted into audio and pass that audio to a messaging system that accepts mp3 and ogg. Ogg is preferred.

I am on Ubuntu and my flow for getting audio string is something like this.

1. Text in Indic language is passed to an API
2. API returns a json with a key value called audioContent. `audioString = response.json()['audio'][0]['audioContent']`
3. The decoded string is arrived by using this `decode_string = base64.b64decode(dat)`

I am currently converting it to mp3 and as you can see I am writing the wave file first and then converting it into an mp3.

```
wav_file = open("output.wav", "wb")
decode_string = base64.b64decode(audioString)
wav_file.write(decode_string)

# Convert this to mp3 file
print('mp3file')
song = AudioSegment.from_wav("output.wav")
song.export("temp.mp3", format="mp3")
```

Is there a way to convert `audioString` directly to ogg file without doing the io?

I've tried torchaudio and pyffmpeg to load `audioString` and do the conversion but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: `ffmpeg -i pipe`  maybe a good way to do it

Comment: How would one do it from within python script? Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

We may write the WAV data to FFmpeg `stdin` pipe, and read the encoded OGG data from FFmpeg `stdout` pipe.
My [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60572878/4926757) describes how to do it with video, and we may apply the same solution to audio.

---

Piping architecture:

```
 --------------------  Encoded      ---------  Encoded      ------------
| Input WAV encoded  | WAV data    | FFmpeg  | OGG data    | Store to   |
| stream             | ----------> | process | ----------> | BytesIO    |
 --------------------  stdin PIPE   ---------  stdout PIPE  -------------
```

The implementation is equivalent to the following shell command:
`cat input.wav | ffmpeg -y -f wav -i pipe: -acodec libopus -f ogg pipe: > test.ogg`

---

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogg), common audio codecs for OGG format are Vorbis, Opus, FLAC, and OggPCM (I selected Opus audio codec).

The example uses [ffmpeg-python](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python) module, but it's just a binding to FFmpeg sub-process (FFmpeg CLI must be installed, and must be in the execution path).

---

Execute FFmpeg sub-process with `stdin` pipe as input and `stdout` pipe as output:

```python
ffmpeg_process = (
    ffmpeg
    .input('pipe:', format='wav')
    .output('pipe:', format='ogg', acodec='libopus')
    .run_async(pipe_stdin=True, pipe_stdout=True)
)
```

The input format is set to `wav`, the output format is set to `ogg` and the selected encoder is `libopus`.

---

Assuming the audio file is relatively large, we can't write the entire WAV data at once, because doing so (without "draining" `stdout` pipe) causes the program execution to halt.

We may have to write the WAV data (in chunks) in a separate thread, and read the encoded data in the main thread.

Here is a sample for the "writer" thread:

```
def writer(ffmpeg_proc, wav_bytes_arr):
    chunk_size = 1024  # Define chunk size to 1024 bytes (the exacts size is not important).
    n_chunks = len(wav_bytes_arr) // chunk_size  # Number of chunks (without the remainder smaller chunk at the end).
    remainder_size = len(wav_bytes_arr) % chunk_size  # Remainder bytes (assume total size is not a multiple of chunk_size).

    for i in range(n_chunks):
        ffmpeg_proc.stdin.write(wav_bytes_arr[i*chunk_size:(i+1)*chunk_size])  # Write chunk of data bytes to stdin pipe of FFmpeg sub-process.

    if (remainder_size > 0):
        ffmpeg_proc.stdin.write(wav_bytes_arr[chunk_size*n_chunks:])  # Write remainder bytes of data bytes to stdin pipe of FFmpeg sub-process.

    ffmpeg_proc.stdin.close()  # Close stdin pipe - closing stdin finish encoding the data, and closes FFmpeg sub-process.
```

The "writer thread" writes the WAV data in small chucks.
The last chunk is smaller (assume the length is not a multiple of chuck size).

At the end, `stdin` pipe is closed.
Closing `stdin` finish encoding the data, and closes FFmpeg sub-process.

---

In the main thread, we are starting the thread, and read encoded "OGG" data from `stdout` pipe (in chunks):

```
thread = threading.Thread(target=writer, args=(ffmpeg_process, wav_bytes_array))
thread.start()

while thread.is_alive():
    ogg_chunk = ffmpeg_process.stdout.read(1024)  # Read chunk with arbitrary size from stdout pipe
    out_stream.write(ogg_chunk)  # Write the encoded chunk to the "in-memory file".
```

---

For reading the remaining data, we may use `ffmpeg_process.communicate()`:

```
# Read the last encoded chunk.
ogg_chunk = ffmpeg_process.communicate()[0]
out_stream.write(ogg_chunk)  # Write the encoded chunk to the "in-memory file".
```

---

Complete code sample:

```
import ffmpeg
import base64
from io import BytesIO
import threading

# Equivalent shell command
# cat input.wav | ffmpeg -y -f wav -i pipe: -acodec libopus -f ogg pipe: > test.ogg

# Writer thread - write the wav data to FFmpeg stdin pipe in small chunks of 1KBytes.
def writer(ffmpeg_proc, wav_bytes_arr):
    chunk_size = 1024  # Define chunk size to 1024 bytes (the exacts size is not important).
    n_chunks = len(wav_bytes_arr) // chunk_size  # Number of chunks (without the remainder smaller chunk at the end).
    remainder_size = len(wav_bytes_arr) % chunk_size  # Remainder bytes (assume total size is not a multiple of chunk_size).

    for i in range(n_chunks):
        ffmpeg_proc.stdin.write(wav_bytes_arr[i*chunk_size:(i+1)*chunk_size])  # Write chunk of data bytes to stdin pipe of FFmpeg sub-process.

    if (remainder_size > 0):
        ffmpeg_proc.stdin.write(wav_bytes_arr[chunk_size*n_chunks:])  # Write remainder bytes of data bytes to stdin pipe of FFmpeg sub-process.

    ffmpeg_proc.stdin.close()  # Close stdin pipe - closing stdin finish encoding the data, and closes FFmpeg sub-process.


# The example reads the decode_string from a file, assume: decoded_bytes_array = base64.b64decode(audioString)
with open('input.wav', 'rb') as f:
    wav_bytes_array = f.read()

# Encode as base64 and decode the base64 - assume the encoded and decoded data are bytes arrays (not UTF-8 strings).
dat = base64.b64encode(wav_bytes_array)  # Encode as Base64 (used for testing - not part of the solution).
wav_bytes_array = base64.b64decode(dat)  # wav_bytes_array applies "decode_string" (from the question).
     
# Execute FFmpeg sub-process with stdin pipe as input and stdout pipe as output.
ffmpeg_process = (
    ffmpeg
    .input('pipe:', format='wav')
    .output('pipe:', format='ogg', acodec='libopus')
    .run_async(pipe_stdin=True, pipe_stdout=True)
)

# Open in-memory file for storing the encoded OGG file
out_stream = BytesIO()

# Starting a thread that writes the WAV data in small chunks.
# We need the thread because writing too much data to stdin pipe at once, causes a deadlock.
thread = threading.Thread(target=writer, args=(ffmpeg_process, wav_bytes_array))
thread.start()

# Read encoded OGG data from stdout pipe of FFmpeg, and write it to out_stream
while thread.is_alive():
    ogg_chunk = ffmpeg_process.stdout.read(1024)  # Read chunk with arbitrary size from stdout pipe
    out_stream.write(ogg_chunk)  # Write the encoded chunk to the "in-memory file".

# Read the last encoded chunk.
ogg_chunk = ffmpeg_process.communicate()[0]
out_stream.write(ogg_chunk)  # Write the encoded chunk to the "in-memory file".
out_stream.seek(0)  # Seek to the beginning of out_stream
ffmpeg_process.wait() # Wait for FFmpeg sub-process to end

# Write out_stream to file - just for testing:
with open('test.ogg', "wb") as f:
    f.write(out_stream.getbuffer())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with TorchAudio in the following manner.

Couple of caveats

1. OPUS support is available via either `libsox` (not available on Windows) or `ffmpeg` (available on Linux/macOS/Windows).
2. On the latest stable release (v0.13), `torchaudio.save` can encode OPUS format using `libsox`. However, underlying implementation on `libsox` is buggy so it is not recommended to use `torchaudio.save` for OPUS.
3. Instead, it is recommended to use `StreamWriter` from [`torchaudio.io`](https://pytorch.org/audio/stable/io.html), which is available as of v0.13. (You need to install `ffmpeg>=4.1,<5`)
4. OPUS only supports 48kHz.
5. OPUS only supports monaural channels. Specifying num_channels something other than 1 does not throw an error, but it produces wrong audio data.

```py
import io
import base64

from torchaudio.io import StreamReader, StreamWriter


# 0. Generate test data
with open("foo.wav", "rb") as file:
    data = file.read()
data = base64.b64encode(data)

# 1. Decode base64
data = base64.b64decode(data)

# 2. Load with torchaudio
reader = StreamReader(io.BytesIO(data))
reader.add_basic_audio_stream(
    frames_per_chunk=-1,  # Decode all the data at once
    format="s16p",  # Use signed 16-bit integer
)
reader.process_all_packets()  # Decode all the data
waveform, = reader.pop_chunks()  # Get the waveform

# 3. Save to OPUS.
writer = StreamWriter("output.opus")
writer.add_audio_stream(
    sample_rate=48000,  # OPUS only supports 48000 Hz
    num_channels=1,  # OPUS only supports monaural
    format="s16",
    encoder_option={"strict": "experimental"},
)
with writer.open():
    writer.write_audio_chunk(0, waveform)
```