# cv2 frames to video byte data for use in streamlit st.video

Tags: python, opencv, streamlit

I have a list of numpy arrays lets call `frames`. I know I can use `cv2.VideoWriter()` to export a series of frames to a video file. However, I would like to just get the byte data instead of actually writing it to a file. My goal is to pass this video to the `st.video()` function. https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/media/st.video. Below is a rough outline of my current setup

```
vid = st.file_uploader(
    label="Upload Video",
    type=["mov", "mp4"]
)
if st.button("Load"):
    v = VideoClassInAnotherFile(vid)
    frames: list[np.ndarray] = v.process() # the function where I manipulate the frames using opencv
    byte_data = ... # TODO: turn the frames into byte data acceptable for st.video
    st.video(byte_data)
```

Comment: A possible solution is to use opencv's VideoWriter to save the data in temporary files that you then upload to streamlit

Comment: Yes. I have already found that solution, but I am trying to achieve the same result without writing to a file at all.

Comment: Then you have to look for a library that stores the n numpy.ndarray in memory (for example in a Io.BytesIo) with the mp4 format. Unfortunately neither opencv nor streamlit have that capacity

Comment: Does this question point to this not being possible? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51052268/streaming-video-in-memory-with-opencv-videowriter-and-python-bytesio/69792994

Comment: That's what I pointed out to you, opencv can't do it.

Comment: I have a code sample that encodes BGR video frames (NumPy arrays) into a memory buffer using ffmpeg-python. It's not going to work with `mov` and `mp4` because they require "seekable output". (Error message is: `muxer does not support non seekable output`). It's working with MKV container, and when the video is not too long. I don't have any experience with streamlit. In case you want me to post an answer, modify your question to something like "How to encode video in memory?".